# Internationalization in a JSP web application?

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

In my current project, we are looking at phasing out our old presentation layer and replacing it with something more modern and more well-known. For various reasons, JSP was chosen as the technology. Possibly in conjunction with Apache Tiles. I should perhaps mention that we are using Spring in the back, if that matters at all.

Internationalization is a requirement, in particular the aspect of showing text messages in the user's language. It surprises me that there is not so much information about this as I had expected.

What I have found is the JSTL `fmt` namespace. Especially using `fmt:message` together with `fmt:param`. However, most references I have found regarding using this technique appear dated.

So, I am wondering if this is still recommended practice? If not, what are the alternatives? Are there any good links on the subjects, describing how to successfully achieve i18n in a web application?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [Internationalization Tag Library](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/tutorial/doc/bnakw.html) section of [The Java EE 5 Tutorial](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/tutorial/doc/), these tags are not outdated and are the standard way to deal with i18n of JSP pages.

Comment: Indeed, its still used and not outdated!

Comment: Thanks, that's pretty much the response I was looking for. I didn't mean that the tags were outdated, just the example pages I was looking at.

Comment: It's however removed in the (no 3 months old yet) Java EE 6 tutorial in favour of pushing Facelets/JSF to the front. JSF supports i18n as good as JSTL did.

Answer (score 1):

i still using JSTL 1.2 for i18n. works like a charm. maybe not updated at all last years but is still does what is must do.