# GWT html files Internationalization

Tags: java, gwt

GWT has a nice docs: https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideI18nLocale

I've localized almost all cases, except html files. 
Is it possible to localize html files in GWT's project ?

For example, how to localize simple html title container, using GWT's i18n possibilities:

```
...
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Text that should be localized :)</title>
  </head>
...
```

Very thanks for your feedback!

Comment: please be more specific, are you trying to localize the document `title` alone, or asking in general about HTML labels?

Comment: I've asked in general, but also write an example to know How-To-Do GWT's i18n with html files.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to localize only titles you can set it with GWT with method:

```
Window.setTitle(strings.title());
```

If you want to localize static text in your HTML you can implement it as jsp files. Here is the answer [Internationalization in a JSP web application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2316485/internationalization-in-a-jsp-web-application)

Comment: Thank you Jamshid, but I have a big one piece of html code that has text among other tags, that could not be covered by GWT's methods :).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change elements/texts outside of your GWT application inside the host page, DOM manipulation could be a way to go:

http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.4/com/google/gwt/user/client/DOM.html
https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideUiDom